# array of CPUSTATES uint64_ts (user, nice, sys, intr, idle) in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sysctl

I required a command in ubuntu to get cpustats, like array of `CPUSTATES uint64_ts(user, nice, sys, intr, idle)`, in FreeBSD when i give command

> "sysctl -a | grep kern.cp_time"

I am able to get the information in FREEBSD command given above.. what will be the command in Ubuntu to get all the cpustat

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions for Ubuntu is http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man3/Sys::Statistics::Linux::CpuStats.3pm.html

Another idea: you can grep+awk output of `top -n1` command.